# Learning OpenGL in Java. Why does glIsFramebuffer() return false?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am new to OpenGL and have very little experience with Java. I'm following some [sample code](http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/source/jogl/JoglStarter.java) and get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: FBObject Init.isFB GL Error 0x501 of FBO[name r/w 1/1, init false, bound false, size 600x600, samples 0/0, modified true/true, depth null, stencil null, colorbuffer attachments: 0/1, with 0 textures: [null], msaa[null, hasSink false, dirty true], state NOT A FBO, obj 0x3300f465]
at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1794)
at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1376)
at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:548)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
```

Looking at [FBObject.java](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/master/src/jogl/classes/com/jogamp/opengl/FBObject.java) starting at 1105 we have the following:

```
// generate fbo ..
gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, val, 0);
fbName = val[0];
if(0 == fbName) {
    throw new GLException("null framebuffer");
}

// bind fbo ..
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbName);
checkNoError(gl, gl.glGetError(), "FBObject Init.bindFB");  // throws GLException if error
if(!gl.glIsFramebuffer(fbName)) {
    checkNoError(gl, GL.GL_INVALID_VALUE, "FBObject Init.isFB"); // throws GLException
}
```

It seems that neither [glGenFramebuffers](http://docs.gl/es2/glGenFramebuffers)() nor [glBindFrameBuffer](http://docs.gl/es2/glBindFramebuffer)() failed, yet [glIsFrameBuffer](http://docs.gl/es2/glIsFramebuffer)() returns false. I'm at a loss.

I've only found one similar [error report](http://forum.jogamp.org/got-error-when-using-GLJPanel-on-Linux-by-Export-DISPLAY-td4031760.html) (from 2014), but there are no replies to that thread. My situation is similar (X11 client and server on separate machines) since I'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 as a guest using VMware Fusion 11.5.1 on macOS 10.15.1 as a host. I can open other windows using java.awt and java.swing so it isn't a trivial X11 issue. I'm using JOGL 2.3 [libraries](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs424/jogl_2_3_support/).

Comment: I advise you to fill a bug report. Please test with a nightly build of JOGL 2.4 too.

Comment: Bug reported here: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1403

Comment: Note that you shouldn't really need to call glIsFrameBuffer so you can still keep working on your program if it doesn't work.